# Two domains accessing same folder

Tags: networking, domain, share

I've just taken a new role in a school and am still familiarizing myself with their network, how ever I have recently been given a task and I'm having a little trouble finding out the fundementals of it.

I have an admin network/domain 10.49.x.x and a classroom network/domian 192.168.1.x both connect to a Proxy server 10.49.202.231/192.168.1.51.

Each domain has it's own shared folders as you'd expect, files and software installs etc,  how ever there is a folder "staff" on the classroom network that all the teachers on the classroom network can access. The users on the admin network would like to access this same folder.

How do I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 2):

can you apply "trust" on these active directory servers?

[trust relationship](http://alahiker28.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Build-Trust-in-a-Relationship) between two AD.DS can solve your problem

Comment: @liamQuinn can you apply it?